# Фильтрация данных SQL

Tags: sql

В БД есть столбец `isDeleted`,которое принимает `true` или `false`,нужно напистаь запрос так что бы после удалении строки,то есть (`isDeleted=false`), павторном запуске программы  `isDeleted` была равна `false` и эта строка не появилось на интерфейсе

Comment: Появилась где? Вы пытаетесь создать view?

Comment: view уже создал,и этот view является источник данных для `DataGridView`,удаление происходит в `DataGridView`,но после предварительного запуска снова появляется ?но думаю если в view написать код что бы там появились только те данные у которых `isDeleted` равно `false` то все будет в порядке

Comment: Ну да, правильно. Это надо делать на уровне самого view... Например, `CREATE VIEW myview AS SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE isDeleted = 0`. Какая у вас платформа БД? Предпологаю что Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: Да Microsoft SQL Server,и все работает,спасибо за поддержку ;)

Comment: Не за что! Я написал это в виде "формального ответа" ниже; можете его принять если он помог :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Процитирую комментарии для сведения.

Это требование указывается на уровне самого view. В Microsoft SQL Server это делается таким образом:

```
CREATE VIEW myview AS
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  mytable 
WHERE isDeleted = 0
```